# Angular - How to include button event?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, button, ng-style

Is there a way to include button in this code which will with click make the same change to an array the same way [ngStyle] does in the following part of the code?

app.component.html

```
<div class="styling">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let a of arr"
        [ngStyle]="changeFont()">
        {{a}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
arr=['car','house','beach','microphone'];
changeFont(){
  return {'font-size.px':15}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you has variables in .ts, and use this variables in the .html.

An example

```
style:any=null  //declare a variable

toogleStyle()  //A function that change the variable
{
  if (!this.style)
    this.style={'font-size':'15px';color:'red'}
  else
    this.style=null
}
```

You can use

```
<div (click)="toogleStyle()" [ngStyle]="style">click me!</div>
```

And see how change the style

As you has "severals" `<li>` you need severals variables if you want severals`<li>` can be "selected" at time or an unique variable if only one `<li>` can be selected at time.

- The "severals variables" are an Array, so to change one element of
  the array you need pass the "index" of the array

  ```
  styles:any[]=[]
  toogleStyle(index:number)  //A function that change the variable
  {
    if (!this.styles[index])
      this.styles[index]={'font-size':'15px';color:'red'}
    else
      this.styles[index]=null
  }

   <ul>
      <!--see using let i=index, i becomes value 0,1,2,3...->
      <li *ngFor = "let a of arr;let i=index"
          <!--see you pass the "index" to the function-->
          [ngStyle]="styles[i]" (click)="toogleStyle(i)">
          {{a}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  ```
- The unique variable is a number that is the "index" selected. For no
  selected index, the variable becomes -1 (Remember that 0 is the fisrt
  element of the array)

  ```
  selectedIndex:number=-1

  toogleStyle(index:number)  //A function that change the variable
  {
    if (this.selectedIndex==index)  //if you click on selected <li>
      this.selectedIndex=-1;
    else
      this.selectedIndex=index;
  }

   <ul>
      <li *ngFor = "let a of arr;let i=index"
          <!--you use the conditional operator (condition)?
                                              value if condition is true:
                                              value if condition is false
          -->
          [ngStyle]="i==selectedIndex?
                        {'font-size':'15px';color:'red'}:
                        null"
          (click)="toogleStyle(i)">
          {{a}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  ```

Comment: This works perfectly when I click on any element of printed array, but I  need button next to array, when clicked it will change the style of every element in a printed array, but anyway thank you a lot, you gave me a bunch of ideas to play with.

Comment: just `<li> <span [ngStyle]="..."> {{a}} </span> <button (click)="toogleStyle(i)> click </button> </li>`