# How to change icon in angular component

Tags: angular, icons, font-awesome, edit, ngx-bootstrap

I want to make editable data and i use fa-icon element for edit icon. When I click on an icon, all the others change in the same way.
[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tegh2.png)
[after click on one icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJc5C.png)

My fa-icon element look a like:
`<fa-icon (click)="EditData($event)" [icon]="['fas', icon]" size="lg"></fa-icon>`

`icon:IconName = 'pen-to-square';`

```
EditData(event:Event)
  {
    const edit = this.icon === 'pen-to-square'?"true" :"false";
    const clicked = event.target as HTMLElement;
    
    const input = clicked.closest('div')?.querySelector('p');
    input!.setAttribute('contenteditable', edit);

    
    if(this.icon === 'floppy-disk')
    {
      this.SaveChanges(input);
    }
    this.icon = this.icon === 'floppy-disk' ? 'pen-to-square' : 'floppy-disk';
  }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't name functions capitalized. That's bad practice.
Second use the correct type for [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent?retiredLocale=de) instead of casting the variable.

Your Problem can be solved by inserting this.icon into the [icon] directive of

Either this way:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="icon"></fa-icon>
```

or this way:

```
<fa-icon icon="{{ icon }}"><fa-icon>
```

As far as I know this is just personal preference.
If this doesn't work please answer me again. I've never personally used Font Awesome. I just used these [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome) as guidance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74199368/angular-how-to-include-button-event/74203850#74203850

Comment: The icons change but i want to change only icon  i clicked. Which is a correct type of mouse event?

Comment: I do not understand what both of you are trying to say to me. I assume you are trying to change only one icon, but you've got multiple. If that is the case you'd need to add a variable for each icon. This can be achieved by using lists or objects:
Assuming you've got a List like this:
icon0
icon1
icon2
You could address these icons like this iconList[1].
If the data structure is more complicated use a Object instead. If this isn't helping please consider to provide further detail of your code or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, that is a case. Is there a way to access to the IconName attribute of the fa-icon element?

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me. I would like to upvote but i need 15 reputation.